# Fatal error: Call to undefined function term_exists()

Tags: fatal-error

In Which version of WordPress did term_exists() first appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its since wordpress 3.0
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists#Change_Log